# Handling extra MVC parameter with different ActionResult

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, routes

I'm working on a website that has 4 individual sections, each with their own controller. These controllers share a few models, however the model will do things slightly differently based on the controller calling it.

The route that I'd like to follow is `{controller}/{model}/{id}/{action}` so I could use `controller1/cars/5/edit` rather than `controller1/editcar/5`.

Is there any way to have my controller understand a model+action combination and handle them with different ActionResults, or am I forced to use an ActionResult on the model name and then use a conditional to figure out what action to take?

In Ruby I could use `get "/controller1/cars/:id/edit" do`. I'm just looking for something similar in MVC4.

**Example routs:**

- `/controller1/cars`

  - *(returns a view containing all cars from controller1)*
- `/controller1/cars/5`

  - *(returns a view containing car with the ID 5 from controller1)*
- `/controller1/cars/5/edit`

  - *(returns a view to edit car with ID 5 from controller1)*
- `/controller2/cars`

  - *(returns a view containing all cars from controller2)*
- `/controller2/boats`

  - *(returns a view containing all boats from controller2)*

Comment: trying to understand your post. what i dont understand is how a complex object like a model can be part of url

Comment: It's not necessarily the model that is being a part of the URL, it's something that I could capture at the controller and handle. Most of my MVC experience is with Ruby, so maybe it's not possible with MVC4. I'd just like my controller to take another URL parameter into consideration when determining what method to call.

Comment: it is definitely possible. Do you mind if the parameter is first in the url? is it an exact word or a variable to be used? there subtleties matter

Comment: I dont understand the question but MVC will bind the {model} part of the url to a parameter on the {controller} and {action} method if that helps.

Comment: @DaveA, as long as the request is still passed to controller1, that would be fine, the order or the parameters isn't important to me (nor are the values, as I would look for specifics within the controller).

Comment: @AlecSanger, I understand better, but am still not clear on couple details... if you're passing the controller and action, the routing is clear. The question makes more sense if you are passing values that are not controller and action but need to be mapped to the controller and action. ex: /steve/debug/edit/1 gets mapped to Tools controller and edit action method. On the other hand, if the action and controller are already in url, what is special to your route?

Comment: @DaveA, using your /steve/debug/edit/1 example as {1}/{2}/{3}/{4}, I'm looking for a way to call a different method in a single controller based on each permutation of {2} and {3} (which would be the name of my model that I'm performing an action on and the action that I'm performing on it).

Comment: Ruby sounds more intriguing than ever. I want some exposure. But to see if this is accomplishable in .net, please add some example routes (3 or 4 preferably) and their resulting actions in your post.

Comment: YES! I think I know how to do this

Comment: Why do you want the controller1 part as a prefix in the url? Wouldn't just /cars/5/edit be nicer? Could you give better examples than controller1 and controller2 such that we better understand what you want

Comment: controller1 would use the same model as controller2, but they would return different views and potentially pass a little extra data. Retrieving a list of cars from controller1 will yield a different list than if they were retrieved from controller2, even though the underlying model of car is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the responses. The reason that I was having so much trouble with this was because I couldn't figure out how to separate controllers with a rout properly. This resulted in my idea breaking away from MVC standards and almost trying to implement a controller of controllers.

When I finally stumbled upon "Areas", I quickly realized that this is what I needed. I was able to add an Area for each section (or area) of my website, and within each area, I could define individual controllers and views, while my models remained in a shared directory outside of all areas. This now works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

I think this route meets your needs. It requires some clever logic in your action methods but should give you the tools to handle it. Read my description of behavior.

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{model}/{id}/{action}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "View", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
```

- This route will Default to an action called View (that will presumably be used for Display) and has an option to direct to a different Action.
- `Model` and `id` will be passed as arguments to you action method. Unfortunately, Model will not be sent as a type but a string (you may feed that into a Factory class).
- if if is left out (eg `/controller2/boats`) it will be passed to your action as a null. This requires logic to handle but gives you the tools to handle it.